# Access Database table with multiple overlapping schedule

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have Access Database table with multiple overlapping schedule. I hought it will be simple for me to create Bu faced with some overlapping existing time range. If an user approves a schedule for one employee. When user goes to approve next schedule with overlapping time for the same employee. I Need to create an alert message  when user approves overlapping schedule and delete  ‘approved’ text from the table. Not much knowledge about VB code or if there is something I can set up in query. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: How do they schedule?  Is it a form in Access that was created?  Or are you just manually entering data into a table?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I have a table with 3 fields: EmpID, StartTime, & EndTime. The Start & End times have the date & time together.

Then I have a form with the same 3 fields.

In the VBA code, under the Before_Update event, I check to see if there's a conflict, and if so, I set the Cancel property to true and display a message. Here's the code:

```
Private Sub Form_BeforeUpdate(Cancel As Integer)
   Dim RS As Recordset
   Dim strSQL As String
   Dim EmpID As Long
   Dim ScheduleStart As String
   Dim ScheduleEnd As String
   EmpID = Me.txtEmpID
   ScheduleStart = Me.txtStartTime
   ScheduleEnd = Me.txtEndTime

   strSQL = ""
   strSQL = strSQL & "SELECT Count(schedule.EmpID) AS Conflict " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "FROM   schedule " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE  ( ( ( Schedule.EmpID ) = @EmpID ) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "         AND ( ( #@ScheduleStart# ) <= [StartTime] ) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "         AND ( ( #@ScheduleEnd# ) > [StartTime] ) ) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "    OR ( ( ( Schedule.EmpID ) = @EmpID ) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "         AND ( ( #@ScheduleStart# ) <= [EndTime] ) " & vbCrLf
   strSQL = strSQL & "         AND ( ( #@ScheduleEnd# ) > [EndTime] ) )"

   strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@EmpID", EmpID)
   strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@ScheduleStart", ScheduleStart)
   strSQL = Replace(strSQL, "@ScheduleEnd", ScheduleEnd)

   Debug.Print strSQL

   Set RS = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL)
   If RS("Conflict") > 0 Then
      Cancel = True
      MsgBox "Conflict Detected", vbExclamation, "Conflict Detected"
   End If
End Sub
```

This looks for 2 scenarios, both using the EmpID.

- If the **ScheduleStart < StartTime** AND **ScheduleEnd > StartTime**
- Or **ScheduleStart < EndTime** AND **ScheduleEnd > EndTime**

Most of the code is building the SQL. It would be much neater if a parameter query was used, but I did it this way because I thought it was clearer.

The Debug.Print strSQL will show you what the query your building looks like.

This has no error checking, so you'l have to put some in. 
Right now, when you enter dates, it has to look like: **6/26/13 4:31 pm**

Comment: I appologize for the delay. can I attach my sample database. The Overime signups aleady in the table with time and date. User only adds the location of OT as OT approved for a line. When user approves one line and next time goes to approve another line for the same person to add location, which may be conflicting with first line that user have approved previously. I need user to get a message that there is a conflict in time with previous approval.
How can I do this? Can you help? I would appreciate your response.
Thank you very much

Comment: Pleae help me I would apprecite any help. I posted a modified question. Because I can not post the entire detail in this box. Thank you

Comment: Then you're going to have to explain the question better. I appears that my answer would work. Only when a conflict is trying to be entered, then a message pops up and the save is cancelled.

Comment: I will be very grateful if you take time to review modified question. The fields in the table, employee name, Date, Start time, end time

Comment: I will be very grateful if you take time to review modified question.The table ‘Sign-ups’, Fields in Sign-Ups: employee name, Date, Start time, end time and Location of work.Except for location, all the fields are pre populated Than approver goes to the form  based on this table and only enters the location as approved.If approver has added a location once and next time when he goes to add location for same employee for different time slot which is conflicting with previous approval.I wanted to set the code that sees conflict.It should delete the location and move to next record. Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I created a sample set of data and a form that looks like this:

[image: screenshot]

And I added this bit of code to the conflicts button to see if your StartTime and StartDate fall between the StartTime/StartDate and EndTime/EndDate of any of the other records.  You would need to modify the code just a bit to also check that the EndTime and EndDate don't fall between as well.

```
Private Sub Test_Button_Click()

Dim myR As Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = "Select * From Sample Where " & _
    "StartDate <= #" & Me.StartDate & "# " & _
    "And StartTime <= #" & Me.StartTime & "# " & _
    "And EndDate >= #" & Me.StartDate & "# " & _
    "And EndTime >= #" & Me.StartTime & "#"

Debug.Print strSQL

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset)

If myR.RecordCount = 0 Then

    Debug.Print "There are no conflicts"

End If

Set myR = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: Your answer is way off. All is does is check to see if at least one record where enddate/time is after startdate/time. Your breaking up the date & time into separate fields for no reason. And this is supposed to check against 1 employee.

Comment: I apologize.  I'm not even close to an expert on this I just try and help as I would do it.  Please feel free to edit my answer or I can remove it if that would be preferable.  I would like to see the proper answer though.  Thank you for the feedback and I'll try and be more mindful of giving a proper answer instead of just a snippet of code.

Comment: Trying to help is a good thing. And you don't have to be an expert. But giving out wrong answers can just make it worse for the person asking questions. And make sure you carefully read what they're asking.

Comment: I was very careful before I became the member and spectacle about posting a question on line and was not sure someone will even read my question. But Now I am glad I did.